# Изменение определенных страниц WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Хочу добавить поиск категорий для своего магазина *при изменении товара, при нажатии на "свойства" у определенного товарав списке продуктов и при массовых изменениях товаров.*

Идея в том, чтобы там, где идет выбор категорий для товара, поставить поиск этих категорий, ибо их много и трудно найти нужное.

Не нашел файлов, отвечающих за эти страницы (при изменении товара, при нажатии на "свойства" у определенного товарав списке продуктов и при массовых изменениях товаров ).

Куда копать, где искать файлы, которые отвечают за данные элементы?

[image: Свойства товара]

[image: Изменение товара]

[image: Множественное изменение товаров]